# What's the second part of the saying "Give someone an inch"?

Tags: popular-refrains

What's the second part of the saying "Give someone an inch"?

I've consulted a number of dictionaries, and they all say the second part is "and they'll take a mile."

This is while in real life I've also heard some alternatives. For example:

You give 'em an inch, and they'll walk all over ya!

You give them an inch, you give them a centimeter.

Give him an inch, he thinks he's a ruler.

Comment: Well as humans are humans they make up all sorts of stuff. But common expression is as you originally stated, "they'll take a mile."

Comment: Give someone a proverb, and they'll mangle it.

Answer (score 4):

**give an inch and they'll take a mile**

> Granting somebody a limited concession will encourage them to take
>   greater liberties  [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_them_an_inch_and_they%27ll_take_a_mile)
>
> Make a small concession and they'll take advantage of you. For
>   example, "I told her she could borrow the car for one day and she's
>   been gone a week - give an inch!" This expression, in slightly different
>   form, was already a proverb in John Heywood's 1546 collection, "Give
>   him an inch and he'll take an ell," and is so well known it is often
>
> shortened (as in the example). The use of mile dates from about 1900. >[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/give-an-inch-and-they-ll-take-a-mile)

From an ell in 1546 to mile ... with 'variations' [sic] to fit all!

[image]

more on creeping changes:

There are a number of other metaphors and expressions which refer to small changes leading to chains of events with undesirable or unexpected consequences, differing in nuances:  [wiktionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel%27s_nose)

> Creeping normality
>          **Foot in the door** – a persuasion technique.
>          **Slippery slope** – an argument, sometimes fallacious.
>          "**The thin end of the wedge**.
>          **Domino effect**.
>          **For Want of a Nail** – the claim that large consequences may follow from inattention to small details.
>          One may as well hang for a sheep as a lamb - deterrence should be proportionate to the incentive to do wrong.
>          Boiling frog – the notion that gradual change tends to go unnoticed until it is too late – often discussed by drawing an
>   analogy to a false story about what will allegedly happen to a frog.
>   in gradually warmed water.
>          This concept was the premise of the Children's book If You Give a Mouse a Cookie. 
>   The Camel's Nose

Comment: "From an eel in 1546" <-- I think you meant "ell" as in the quote. An "ell" is a unit of measure ~45 inches.

Comment: @Kelvin indeed, tks.

Answer (score 0):

> Give someone an inch, "and they'll take a mile"

is perhaps the most common way of ending the saying or proverb.

The other suggestions you cite are variations on the theme, and frankly, I like them. I guess you'd call those alternatives the result of "thinking outside the box"!

Thinking outside the box, you could change the following saying

> Your freedom to swing your arm ends where my nose begins,

and turn it into

> Your freedom to swing your arm ends where my temper begins.

I'm not suggesting that the above variation is very good, but it paints an interesting picture of a person whose nose has just been hit by a swinging arm, and in response he or she loses their temper and swings back!